# Geometrical interpretation of derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, tangent-line, linear-approximation

**Statement**: being unable to solve the famous derivative's limit at the point $P$ is actually equals to being unable to graph a tangent line to that point $P$.

Statement seems to be incomplete. At any given point one might graph as much tangent lines as he would like to. But the problem is that those tangents won't convey any "good" approximation for the original $f(x)$ at the given point $P$. As such, could I conclude something like:

> Being unable to solve the famous derivative's limit at the point P is actually equals to being unable to graph a tangent line to that point P SUCH THAT IT PROVIDES "GOOD" LINEAR APPROXIMATION AROUND POINT P.

Or, slightly modified:

> Among all possible tangent lines to the point P, there might be exactly one representing the best possible approximation; in case it exists, f(x) is differentiable at that point. Otherwise none of possible tangent lines to the point P gives "good" approximation.

Am I right?

P.S.

"Good" approximations means that $|f(x) - l(x)| \lt \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ while $x \rightarrow P_x$.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "tangent line" means geometrically; a differentiable function can only have one tangent line at a given point. This is a geometric property, distinct from the related analytic properties.

Comment: @Ian according to my knowledge, a tangent line is a line that shares at least 1 point with original function. Which means a tangent line to point $P$ of $f(x)$ shares... $P$ with it. Captain Obvious.

Comment: Nice functions like $f(x)=x^2$ are usually considered to have only one tangent at each point. So your definition of "tangent at $P$" as "any line that intersects the graph at $P$" runs contrary to the established definition.

Comment: @Arthur it probably has came historically due to obvious pointlessness of having infinite tangent lines which have no value, give no benefits. But hold a second. How many lines could you possible have passing single given point? So, being as restrict as possible, there is an infinity of them indeed.

Comment: So if I get this straight: you think the definition of "tangent" is bad, so you make your own? And then you come here because you can't make sense of results referring to the classical definition when you use your new definition?

Comment: @Arthur well, the only definition I have seen so far, is a line, guaranteed to share at least single point with original function. According to this definition there are infinite numbers of such a lines. The "definition" you provided is more a common agreement rather than a well-established math definition. And, btw, I do make sense of results, the question was did not I miss something?

Comment: @Arthur since whole differentiation is about approximation, the problem of having best approximation ever possible makes a perfect sense to me.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, a tangent is not just "the best" approximation. It's an approximation that fulfills certain very specific criteria for _how good_ an approximation it is. If there is such a line, then there is only one. But there isn't always such a line, and whether there is one corresponds exactly to whether the function is differentiable.

Comment: @Arthur an the criteria is: the closer you get to the $P$, which is shared by both funcs, the less is error?

Comment: A tangent line is not just a line that intersects the point. For a curve with a fixed concavity (all concave down or all concave up), there is only one point of intersection. The geometry is a bit less explicit for more general curves.

Comment: @СергейБоголюбов The criteria in question are that $f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ goes to zero faster than $x-x_0$, i.e. $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)}{x-x_0} = 0$. This can only occur for one number $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: By definition, a tangent line to a (non-self-intersecting) curve $\gamma$ at $P$ is the limit of lines $P'P''$ with $P',P''\in\gamma$, when $P',P''\to P$. So, having the only intersection point with a curve is neither sufficient nor necessary. For the latter, consider $\{(x,x^3)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ and any tangent to it at a point other than $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @Ian where this criteria comes from? I can describe the other one: $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0 : \forall x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta) : |f(x) - l(x)| \lt \epsilon$. In other words, you give me the maximum error you can stand, I reply with an interval, where $l(x)$ approximates around point $a$ goodly enough.

Comment: That is non-unique: for any $f$ you could take $l(x)=f(a)$, for example. Tangent lines give a better approximation than that.

Comment: @Ian could it be proved somehow? the fact that unique tangent line is indeed better than that?